# Сохранение состояний Fragment`ов

Tags: java, android

У меня на главной странице `BottomNavigationView(BNV)`, а для контента использую `FrameLayout`, не `ViewPager`. В `BNV` 5 пунктов, соответственно 5 `Frament`ов. В каждом `Fragment` может быть сколько угодно фрагментов. Для переходов я использовал метод `replace` и все работает кроме, сохранения данных, то есть я перехожу на одну страницу и когда обратно, то есть когда нажимаю кнопку назад, то предыдущая страница обновляется.

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "nothing on backStack, calling super");
        finish();
    } else {
        fm.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
```

Чтобы решить это, я начал использовать `show/hide` вместо `replace`, но тут писать куча кода и переход назад с `show/hide` не работает.

Вопрос: Как решить вопрос с сохранение данных и переходов назад? Кто как решал эту проблему?

Comment: Учитывая то, что вы закопались в сложности - скорее всего вы неправильно выбрали подход. Я бы сделал 5 фрагментов, которые сетятся в один контейнер по клику на BNV, а с них бы проваливался в разные активити, где был бы реализован "колодец" с остальным стеком экранов, которые должны быть под этим фрагментом. Это если BNV принципиален

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит "с них бы проваливался в разные активити", если переходить с этого `Activity` на другой `Activity`, то BNV исчезнет, то есть останется в предыдущем `Activity`. Не могли бы вы подробнее пояснить?

Comment: Всё правильно. Обычно переключение между табами это "лицевые экраны", а дальше уже конкретный флоу, можно подписать его название в тулбаре. Либо можно сделать для активити отступ от экрана по размеру BNV, чтобы её было видно, костыль, но поможет) Единственное, что по клику на BNV надо будет ззакрывать текущий флоу.

Comment: Если прям не хотите уходить от BNV ПРЯМ ВЕЗДЕ, то можете сделать енам, описывающий стейты, по нажатию на bnv обрабатывать метод в активити, который принимает на вход описанный в енам стейт, и мапит по нему фрагмент в контейнер

Comment: Это удобно, потому что при повороте экрана или при другом пересоздании активити вы сможете просто сохранить в onSaveInstanceState значение енама и заресторить состояние после пересоздания

Comment: самое сложное при таком подходе хранить данные каждого фрагмента - но тут как уж архитектуру построите. Без понимания того, что у вас за приложение я не смогу сказать вообще ничего

Comment: Представьте инстаграмм. Как переходы между `Fragment` в `BTM` и внутренние `Fragment` работают. И сохранение данных. Я ориентируюсь сейчас на инсту